# Access Linux with Non interactive account

Tags: ssh, account-restrictions

Not sure if the question makes sense. But, here it goes.

We are developing a Web application (.NET) that basically checks status of some Linux servers and services running inside them. We are supposed to do this with a service account that doesn't have interactive login access to the Linux severs. Is there any work around to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to collect the information by logging into the Linux servers, you could create a script or program on the servers to generate the information that you're looking to collect.  Then create a user on those servers whose shell is that script.  With that, when you log in as that user the script/program will run, generate the information of interest, and terminate.